# Can't use Redux props in firebase redirect results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build Google Authentication in React + Redux + Firebase. And I want to create user after google authentication. But `this.props.createUser()` is not working after Redirects on Firebase.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

**app/src/components/home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import firebase from "../config/firebase";
import { createUser } from "../actions";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: null
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    console.log("this", this.props);
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ user });

      if (user) {
        this.props.history.push("/user/settings");
      }
    });

    firebase
      .auth()
      .getRedirectResult()
      .then(function(result) {
        if (result.credential) {
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          console.log("token", token);
        }
        var user = result.user;
        // Successfully got a user but type error in below
        this.props.createUser(user);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      });
  }

  onLogin = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="btn btnPrimary" onClick={this.onLogin}>
        <span>Google Signin</span>
      </button>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ user }) {
  return { user: user };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createUser })(Home);
```

**app/src/actions/index.js**

```
import firebase from "../config/firebase";

export function createUser(user) {
  console.log('user', user)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declare the callback with the `function` keyword, `this` inside the function refers to the function itself and not to the class on which you declared the `componentWillMount` method.

The simplest solution is to use fat arrow notation, as you do elsewhere already:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .getRedirectResult()
  .then((result) => {
    if (result.credential) {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      console.log("token", token);
    }
    var user = result.user;
    // Successfully got a user but type error in below
    this.props.createUser(user);
  })
```

Also see this answer on the cause of the problem, and other solutions: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an arrow function here:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .getRedirectResult()
  .then(function(result) {
    if (result.credential) {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      console.log("token", token);
    }
    var user = result.user;
    // Successfully got a user but type error in below
    this.props.createUser(user);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  });
```

should be:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .getRedirectResult()
  .then((result) => {
    if (result.credential) {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      console.log("token", token);
    }
    var user = result.user;
    // Successfully got a user but type error in below
    this.props.createUser(user);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  });
```

[The `function() {}` keyword is eating your `this` value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)